# Memory Leak with memcpy and std::queue

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a code that reads large files and copy them from somewwhere to somewhere.

Firstly I take the data from network and copy to a fixed size buffer that is;

```
fixed_buffer[100000];
```

and then i copy the data that comes from network to it whenever data comes from network.the data that comes network is always smaller than buffer size;

```
memcpy(fixed_buffer,network_data_buffer,network_data_size);
```

than I copy it to a buffer that has a greater size that is

```
fixed_buffer_2[200000];

memcpy(fixed_buffer_2,fized_buffer,sizeof_fixed_buffer);
```

than I push the fixed_buffer_2 to a std::queue and another thread pops it from queue and processes.

So there are few memcpys in my code.I tested my code with a leak detector and saw that in the phase:

```
std::queue.push(fixed_buffer_2);
std::queue.pop();
```

there are memory leaks.I am suspicious of the memcpy operations and pushing ot queue.How can i avoid this.What is the problem?

Comment: a) show us the code, b) do you use proper synchronization? c) do you use dynamic memory for buffers? d) valgrind.

Comment: `std::queue.push(fixed_buffer_2);` thats quite far away from real code. Show real code, otherwise we don't know what you are doing, and when we don't know what you are doing, how should we point out what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Why? Why not just write direct from the original buffer to the target file? You don't need all this complication. It's just slowing you down, wasting  memory and CPU, and causing bugs like this.